# Texture Coordinates for OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a Tilesheet loaded as a texture and I am trying to render a single tile from the texture

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TileSheet);
float TY = (Tile / 16) * 0.0625;
float TX = (Tile % 16) * 0.0625;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(TX, TY); glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(X, Y, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(TX + 0.0625, TY); glVertex3f(X + TILE_SIZE, Y, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(TX + 0.0625, TY + 0.0625); glVertex3f(X + TILE_SIZE, Y + TILE_SIZE, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(TX, TY + 0.0625); glVertex3f(X, Y + TILE_SIZE, 0);
glEnd();
```

`Tile` is an `int` and represents what tile to render on the tilesheet
`0.0625` being Width and Height of my Tilesheet / How many tiles per line `(512 / 16)`

So in the tilesheet it is 16 tiles wide so if `Tile` was 16 it would be the tile on the left and one tile from the top of the tilesheet. But this is what I get [image]

So the top left is `[0][0]` and the bottom right is `[1][0]` I dont see what im doing wrong. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I should also mention that if `Tile == 0` it renders the correct tile, but as soon as `Tile > 0` the tile ends up as above.

Comment: Unclear on the problem exactly.  Is it that little border on the top left of your result?

Comment: nope, that is poor screenshot editing. Its the blending of the Grass tile and the Brick Tile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `glTexCoord2f` twice before you call `glVertex3f`. That does not look right.

It looks like this line:

`glTexCoord2f(TX, TY); glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(X, Y, 0);`

Should be:

`glTexCoord2f(TX, TY); glVertex3f(X, Y, 0);`

Comment: I cannot believe that! now I feel stupid for asking :( I been tinkering with this for the past 20 min...

Comment: We all make typos from time to time! Especially while experimenting / tinkering / copy pasting things all over the place. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.

Comment: @Elgoog I wonder though, why you found it to be the correct solution, but not that good/helpful to up-vote it?